# WildFly + java Preferences cannot find custom preferences class in classpath

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

I am deploying an EAR with the below structure to Wildfly 9.0.2

```
my.ear  
  |-my.sar    (it is a SAR archive)
  |-lib
     |-myPreferencesImpl.jar
```

I am able to load the classes in lib/myPreferencesImpl.jar from my.sar (like class.forname(com.my.PreferencesFactory) directly. However, java.util.prefs.Preferences.factory is not able to load com.my.PreferencesFactory. I am passing `Djava.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory=com.my.PreferencesFactory` as command line parameter during WildFly startup.

Below is the exception thrown.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.my.PreferencesFactory from [Module "org.jboss.as.jmx:main" from local module loader @76a3e297 (finder: local module finder @4d3167f4 (roots: /CSA_wildfly/wildfly/modules,/CSA_wildfly/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:130)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at java.util.prefs.Preferences.factory(Preferences.java:254)
```

Please help me fix this.

**UPDATE:**
I finally fixed by migrating the startup service using JMX Service to a @Singleton + @Startup EJB. No other changes were required.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass the arg `Djava.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory=com.my.PreferencesFactory` in command line, Wildfly is going to look for the class in the classes available to it, which is provided by way of [modules](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly?_sscc=t) . During the Wildfly bootup, it's not even going to know that there is a application with that class present, neither can it provide the same class to other deployments on the same container. So if you want the command line arg to work, make sure the [deploy the Factory implementation as a Wildfly module](http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=1933).

Comment: It is the application (my.sar) that is calling `java.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory` to instantiate `com.my.PreferencesFactory`. This happens after the Wildfly bootup. So why would that not work?

Comment: It's actually not set until `java.util.prefs.Preferences` is initialized. So it should work. However no other deployments or any server dependencies would be able to use the preferences API so it has to be in a module. In this case JMX is attempting to use the preferences API and can't.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins you should post this as a answer.

Comment: Well you're answer is correct I was just clarifying a point :)

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins - fixed it by migrating the startup service using JMX Service to a Singleton + Startup EJB. No other changes were required.

Comment: Just keep in mind no other application will be able to use the preferences API.